# How to define [] for class in Python?

Tags: python

I feel like this question has already been asked and answered, yet I couldn't find anything on-topic, so excuse me if it is so. I want to define the behaviour of [] brackets when applied to class, similar to `def []=()` construct in ruby, so that calling Python `obj['foo']` would actually call some `[](self, what)` method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's all in the docs: [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Answer (score 7):

This is done with `__getitem___` in Python.

Here is a list of all the operators:
http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html

Comment: Thanks for linking the entire list of operators. It eluded me, and probably many others.

Answer (score 5):

define a method in your class with `__getitem__(key)` and `__setitem__(key, value)`

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Section 3.4 in the above link shows you all or most of the operators you can overload in Python.  The one you want to overload is

```
__getitem__()
```